# React router hello world doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, react-router

The interwebs seem to be filled with old react-router examples that don't work. I've been doing react and flux for a while now and I'm shocked at how hard it is to get this trivial amount of code working. I'm using react-router 2.0.0.

Can anyone assist? Here's my entry point App.js

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Router = require('react-router');
var Route = require('react-router').Route;
var App = require('./components/App.react');

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
        <Route path="/" component={App} />
  </Router>, 
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

This fails with errors:

> Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined,
>   boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a
>   ReactClass (for composite components).
>
> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a
>   string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
>   components) but got: object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
var Router = require('react-router');
```

to

```
var Router = require('react-router').Router;
```

and it should work.

Comment: This seems to have changed in v1.0.0: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/upgrade-guides/v1.0.0.md

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm glad it was super simple.

Comment: Next up: the link doesn't work. Do you know a good source for guides on this? I just added a nested about route and a link to route to about and it doesn't do anything even though the url changes

Comment: I recommend the [react-router tutorial](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/blob/start/lessons/01-setting-up.md), but it is using ES6. 

For me until now, whenever the url changed but nothing happened, there was an error in the component I was navigating to. Could you post the routes and the component with the Link, eventually the component you navigate to? If you have the full code somewhere on github, I can have a look at it.